# On the role of PDFs in the determination of impossible events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let's consider a random variable $X$ distributed according to a PDF $p(x):\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Is it true to say that for any $x_0:p(x_0)=0$ the event $X=x_0$ is impossible?
By impossible, I mean that if we simulate $X$ we never observe in the sample the value $x_0$.

My question is complementary to the well-known fact that $X=x_0$ is almost impossible, in the sense that $\mathbb{P}(X=x_0)=0$, but $X=x_0$ can still happen (i.e., if we simulate $X$ then we can observe the value $x_0$ in the sample).

Comment: As your second paragraph says, probabilities of $0$ do not mean "impossible".  Why do you think this does not apply to the argument in your first paragraph?

Comment: I don't know if it applies or not to the first paragraph

Comment: What is your definition of "impossible event"? I don't think the term "impossible event" would be a useful addition to the terminology of probability theory; the existing terms "empty set" and "probability zero" are unambiguous and don't need synonyms. Of the two, "probability zero" is the one that corresponds to the everyday notion of "impossible"; probability zero events are never observed to happen.